# Gatsby online payment gateway

Tags: javascript, reactjs, payment-gateway, gatsby

I'm working on a website about donation using Gatsby v2 (Reactjs) and I'm on last phase to connect the website to the online payment gateway in my Country Morocco, so the users can use there credit card to do donation but "the module integration kit for online payment" script I use has just C#.net, PHP, VB.NET, JSP versions, they have not the JavaScript version. Does is possible to connect Gatsby with any version of that script??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably ask this on a Gatsby specific platform, not on a React specific platform.

Comment: @Xizam Gatsby is just a generator for React so it's work the same.

Comment: Hi Ragnar — there's really not enough information to answer your question adequately. It's very likely to be possible, but without knowing the endpoints exposed by the payment gateway you're using it's hard to be more specific. It's likely that you would need something running server side to process transactions in any case.